# How to set Background in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl-es

I've newly learnt OpenGL and I am developing a Game using OpenGL. I don't know how to set an image as background using OpenGL, for example in Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some discussion about this [here](http://www.anddev.org/background_images_in_opengl-t9507.html).

Basically is just a quad with a texture. Take care when testing it as it seems some emulators will get some drastic FPS reduction, not sure why.